# Qt - Relation between two textedits

Tags: c++, qt

I've got a question about a TextEdit class in Qt.

I'm trying to create a Diff-like program in Qt. So far I'm using the `QTextBlock` with `QTextCursor` to color the changed lines on my `QPlainTextEdit`.
My question is - how can I create that 'spout' that shows the relations between two lines, just like in meld?

[image]

As you can see on the screenshot, 10 blue lines in the first file correspond to 4 blue lines in the second file

Comment: You should consider the `QTextDocument` class rather than using two different `QTextEdit`. It would be easier to work on the same document with two columns.

Comment: The question is asking about comparing documents; it isn't the same document with two columns.

Comment: I suggested to use a `QTextDocument` to create a diff between two texts inside a same `QTextEdit`. Trying to use two different widgets is not a good idea, IMHO (how to sync both `QTextEdit` scrollbars, find the good alignment, etc.). But, it's quite easy to get or set the absolute position of a block in a `QTextDocument`

Answer (score 0):

I think you're going to have to build your own custom widget, derived from QWidget, for that center section, and then handle the painting yourself. The tricky part will likely be the issue of informing the center widget where the colored lines are on each side (which will be related to how they're scrolled) so that it knows where to put the colored sections.